# I can not scrape a webpage with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I'm trying to scrap https://www.crowdcube.com/investments?sector=technology with BeautifulSoup in Python 3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "D:\DataVisualization\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "D:\DataVisualization\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "D:\DataVisualization\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "D:\DataVisualization\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "D:\DataVisualization\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "D:\DataVisualization\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Can you post the Beautiful Soup code you're using?

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, re

data = {
        'title' : [],
        'description' : []
}

l=('https://www.crowdcube.com/investment')
tree= BeautifulSoup(l, 'lxml')

#title
title=tree.find_all('div',{'cc-cardOpportunity__body'})
data['title']=tree.find('h1')   

#description
description=tree.find_all('div',{'class':'cc-cardOpportunity__body'})

data['description'].append(description[1].find('p').get_text()

data

Comment: I can not scrapy this website :(

Answer (score -1):

use requests and this site do not need UA:

```
In [23]: import requests

In [24]: r = requests.get('https://www.crowdcube.com/investments?sector=technology')

In [25]: r.status_code
Out[25]: 200
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for Beautiful Soup.

Comment: @bejado do you have any idea the difference between `bs4` and `urllib` or `requests`? how does `403` concern with `bs4`?

Comment: I'm not sure why OP is getting a 403, but the question is specifically asking _why_ a 403 is issued when using Beautiful Soup. You answer does not address that.